# How would I cipher this string with a longer cipher?

Tags: python-2.7

I have to cipher a string with a longer cipher. I'm not sure how to do it.

```
key = input()

def function(entry, key):
    length = len(entry)
    kk = key * (1 + length // len(key))   
    out = ""
    p = 0

    for i in entry:
        out += chr((ord(i)-97) % 26)
```

Comment: Can you include some inputs and outputs too?

Comment: for i in vstup:
        if "a" < i < "z":
            posun = ord(pomocny[p])-97 + 1
            posunute = (ord(i) - 97 + posun)%26 + 97
            pismeno = chr(posunute)
            vystup += pismeno
        else:
            vystup += i